# How to detect language of the WatchKit voice-to-text input?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I am trying to get some input from the user on the Apple Watch using `presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions`. I wonder what happens if user speaks multiple languages – is there a way to detect which language has he spoken?

Also, is there a way to find out what languages are set in his preferences?

Answer (score 1):

Not having a Watch on hand, I don't think anyone here knows. (*Edit: this was first posted before the Watch launched.*) But even though it'd be really cool if there were dictation software that could guess *cual idioma* で話しています from word to word, watchOS is no different than iOS in that respect.

In iOS, Siri listens only in the language you set in Settings, and dictation listens only in the language of the active keyboard (whose microphone button you pressed to start dictation).

In watchOS, Siri likewise has a set language. Dictation is based on the keyboard language last used on your paired phone, but you can also change the language during text entry with a force press. That's a user choice for a system service, so it's opaque to the app, just like choice of keyboard is to an iOS app. (You're welcome to perform some sort of text analysis of you want to know what language of text the user has entered.)

Comment: I guess it should be like a dictation feature on iOS, at least conceptually, however as there is no way to set the source language I wonder if apple will go an extra mile and auto detect input source.

Comment: Detecting the language of an utterance is nowadays not implemented at consumer level solutions like this. I was expecting at least, to have a way to programmatically determine which language is currently selected, but no! disappointed.